# Delete oldest entries with two duplicate columns from a table - SQL

Tags: sql

```
 SELECT column1, column2, count(*) as duplicate 
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY column1, column2 HAVING count(*)> 1 ;

ID   column1 column2 timestamp
abc  123     1       2020-02-03 19:36:27
xyz  123     1       2020-02-02 15:36:27
```

column1 and column2 is a unique combination with duplicate entry.

The above queries gives the entries that have duplicates. We want to delete the oldest entries based on another column timestamp

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
delete from t
    where t.timestamp > (select min(t2.timestamp)
                         from t t2
                         where t2.column1 = t.column1 and t2.column2 = t.column2
                        );
```

Comment: @Sun Su, if you are looking to retain the latest entry, you can replace the '>' and 'min' with '<' and 'max'

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE 
FROM table a
JOIN (
SELECT id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY column1, column2 ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS rownum
FROM table ) b
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE rownum > 1
```

You can use row_number function to get an ordered ranking of the results. Partitioning by column1 and column2 will restart the row number at each change in those values. Ordering by your timestamp descending will start your count with the newest record, so deleting anything where a rownum > 1 would keep only the newest record. If you needed something like a top 3, you would simply change the rownum > from 1 to 3.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.